# How to present task in jira as they are in rally

Tags: jira, rally, agile, scrum

Our team is transitioning from rally as agile development tool to jira. And we are having problem to view user stories data as we used to in rally. For instance this is picture that represents two user stories with corresponding child tasks.[image: Rally screenshot sample]

On this picture we can see user stories points, tasks hours and state of every task and story. And when every task is moved to completed state whole user story is marked as completed.

How can we achieve something like this in jira?

Comment: This is what the Issues view looks like (without the expand/contract) where advanced filtering can be done, columns can be added / removed (and sorted), and can then be saved as private or shared Filters. In a sense, this is the most bare-bones feature of JIRA.
Regarding "every task moved", I'll answer that separately.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For automatically transitioning a parent (or linked) issue, one of the better plugins to use is the JMWE add-on.

1. Go to `Admin > Issues > Workflow` and edit the workflow in question
2. On the transition that should trigger the parent's status shift, add a `Post Function`
   [image]
3. Choose `Transition parent issue (JMWE add-on)`
   [image]
4. Type out the transition desired, tick off `Conditional Execution` and type this into the condition:

   `{% set stories = issue | epic | stories %}
   {% set trigger = true %}
   {% for story in stories %}
     {% if story.fields.status.name != "Resolved" %}
         {% set trigger = false %}
     {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   {{ trigger }}`

   [image]

For other / similar examples of conditionals, see the [JMWE conditional execution page](https://innovalog.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JMWEC/Conditional+execution) and the [JMWE nunjucks issue properties page](https://innovalog.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JMWEC/How+to+insert+information+using+Nunjucks+annotations#HowtoinsertinformationusingNunjucksannotations-Filters)